# Packing Gatling test suite as an executable binary

Tags: sbt, gatling

I have written a suite of simulations using Gatling, and I was wondering if it would be possible to package them into a binary as one would with a Play application for instance, in order to execute it without needing sbt ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) or [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack).